# base conversion question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi i had a quick question regarding converting bases. say if i wanted to convert 2301(base 5) to base 8 would a simple way of doing this be to first convert it to base 10 and then convert that to base eight. and if so yes, can i apply this same technique to other conversions such as octal to hexadecimal etc?

Comment: You can always do this, but once you get used  to conversion, you will not find the need to come to base $10$ in the middle. This is normally not done, when the bases are powers of two, because then there is a different trick

Comment: Yes and Yes....